# Titanium: Zoom to a specific row of a table

Tags: javascript, focus, scroll, titanium, zooming

I have a tableview created.

There are multiple rows in the tableview.

When I click on Row 12, I want the screen to scroll up and have Row 12 at the top of the screen.

Is there any way to control the scrolling to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using this function:

> [Titanium.UI.TableView.scrollToIndex](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.5/Titanium.UI.TableView.scrollToIndex-method.html)